Redis relational data cache invalidation problem
I’m facing a cache invalidation problem in Redis, particularly with relational data.
For example, I have a User object:
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John"
}

And a UserClass object:
{
    "user_id": 1,
    "class_id": 3
}

I have an API that retrieves all users by class_id, and I store this data in Redis using the key users:class:3, which contains an array of users. I also have an API that retrieves a user by ID using the key user:1.
The problem arises when someone updates, inserts, or deletes user data. I need to remove all corresponding user data from the cache. Removing the user by the ID key is straightforward, but to invalidate the cache for the user by class, I currently have to query the database to get all classes the user is associated with and then remove the corresponding keys in Redis one by one using class_id.
This approach doesn’t seem optimal, especially if the user has other relationships beyond classes. Each time, I would need to query the database again to find the corresponding keys, leading to a lot of operations. Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this problem more efficiently?

Not sure if you are using Redis client-side caching or not when referring to invalidation, but the data modeling problem can be approached as follows.
You want the ability to classify users by class_id, and retrieve data by class_id or using additional relations.
Your approach is manual secondary indexing, which is inefficient due to the effort to maintain relationships, make scans, serialize and deserialize data in the string.
I suggest using the Redis Stack capabilities (which will also be available in the standard Redis Community Edition 8).
Then you would create an index as follows:
FT.CREATE user_idx ON HASH PREFIX 1 user: SCHEMA class_id AS class_id TAG attributes AS attributes TAG SEPARATOR ","

Insert data with:
HSET user:1 id 1 class_id 3 name "John" attributes "class1,class2"
HSET user:2 id 2 class_id 7 name "Mary" attributes "class1,class25"
HSET user:3 id 3 class_id 7 name "Ted" attributes "class2"
HSET user:4 id 4 class_id 7 name "Shawn" attributes "class1,class32"
HSET user:5 id 5 class_id 3 name "Mike" attributes "class12,class13"

And filter by class or attribute
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.SEARCH user_idx '@class_id:{3}' RETURN 1 name
1) (integer) 2
2) "user:1"
3) 1) "name"
    2) "John"
4) "user:5"
5) 1) "name"
    2) "Mike"

127.0.0.1:6379> FT.SEARCH user_idx '@class_id:{7}' RETURN 1 name
1) (integer) 3
2) "user:2"
3) 1) "name"
    2) "Mary"
4) "user:3"
5) 1) "name"
    2) "Ted"
6) "user:4"
7) 1) "name"
    2) "Shawn"

127.0.0.1:6379> FT.SEARCH user_idx '@attributes:{class2}' RETURN 1 name
1) (integer) 2
2) "user:1"
3) 1) "name"
    2) "John"
4) "user:3"
5) 1) "name"
    2) "Ted"

These commands are available also in the Redis supported client libraries. You can read more about the search and query capability here. If you'd rather user JSON to model your data, you can do that as well.
This should help you model and search your data without any overhead or maintenance effort.

Hey bro, thanks for the solution! After implementing those changes, I think I'm facing another problem. For example, if I retrieve all users with class_id 3 from the cache, how can I ensure that the cache contains all the users in that class?

Not sure if I get the question fully. Why shouldn't it return all the values that are tagged by that class_id? Unless you delete or expire data (in such a case the index is updated transparently to remove those entries), all the data will be returned. Make sure you use the clause [LIMIT offset num], by default only 10 results are returned. Check the related doc https://redis.io/docs/latest/commands/ft.search/

For example, let's say I have two APIs, getUserByID and getUsersByClassID. Users with class ID 3 are users 1, 2, 3, and 4. Then, if someone gets a user with ID 2, I store the user data in the cache. Then, when someone hits the getUsersByClassID, I search for all users with class_id 3, but only one user which is the user with ID 2 is found in the cache. How can I ensure that all the users returned from the cache are all users in the class?

What kind of caching pattern are you thinking of? If Redis is a cache with cache-aside pattern, FT.SEARCH does not make a lot of sense because the cache does not have all the data. If the plan is write-through, it makes sense, as the cache will store a replica of all the data: so you can index and search, everything will be in the cache.
You can model the problem with cache-aside too. You could cache getUsersByClassID as a Redis set with TTL.
SADD users:3 1 5
EXPIRE users:3 60
You will read stale data for some time, but after expiration data is read again from the primary store
